# Periodic tasks not working in Django Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

This is my periodic task:

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask
from celery.registry import tasks
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

class MyTask(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = timedelta(minutes=1)

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        self.get_logger().info("Time now: " + datetime.now())
        print("Time now: " + datetime.now())

tasks.register(MyTask)
```

I started my django server at python manage.py runserver and also started celery with python manage.py celeryd -B.

Still nothing gets printed on the command prompt though according to the code, the time should have been printed.

Any idea what's going wrong here? Seems quite straight forward.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'proc': {
        "task": "tasks.processing",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=60),
        },
    }
```

in your `celeryconfig.py` or in django's settings.py
See full documentaion here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your system time-zone if is the same as Django time zone.

For Django: Change it from settings file.

For linux operating system: change it like that: `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime`